# Placing div over button on click

Tags: html, css

I want to place a div over the button once the button is clicked like the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PetZ.png

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: yes but for what reason? why not just disable it, or remove it completely?

Comment: Disable it? For what?

Comment: @Dark1007 I think there's an ambiguity here: "place a div over the button" could mean creating a div which overlaps and hides the button, or creating a div (such as the "input something" div) vertically higher up on the page than the button (and the button is still visible lower down), as in your image. You should clarify which one you mean.

Comment: i.e. do you mean "over the button" as in [above it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RwqRy.png), or [overlapping it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7Cp.png)? I think you mean the former, but "over the button" would generally be taken to mean the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the button and the div panel in a parent div. make the popup div absolute and hidden.

```
.parent-div{
   position:relative;
}

.popup-div{
   position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;
   z-index:10;
   display:none;
}
```

show the popup-div on btn click.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
   $(".popup-div").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that! Suppose you are having the button on the very bottom left of your page.

I will just show the basic, only the code for button and the div. Hope it helps.

css for that:

```
.button, .div {
position: absolute;
bottm: 0;
left: 0;
}
.div {
display: none; // to make it hidden.
}
```

the HTML would be:

```
<button class="button">I am button</button>
<div class="div">I am on the button!</div>
```

Now the jQuery should be something like:

```
$(document)ready(function() {
  $(".button")click(function() {
    $(".div").show();
  })
})
```